# Clarification on intuition behind one to one correspondence?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

My book - Discrete Mathematics and its Applications

This is my book's definition on if an infinite set is countable
[image]

And the example it gave [image]

The "infinite set is countable if and only if it is possible to list the elements of the set in a sequence" makes sense to me. That is say even integers is countable because you can start listing them out -2, 4, -2, -4, and so on....

What I'am struggling is how showing a one to one correspondence between this set(even) integers and the set of positive integers goes to show. One to one correspondence as in a function that maps the set of positive integers to to perhaps countable set(even integers) I don't understand the logic behind this at all. Can anyone clarify this? I feel like this is making it a lot more complicated than it needs to be. If I encountered a problem like show that the set R is not accountable, I would show that you can't count it because the decimal point would just keep going - 0.001, 0.00001. How would this one to one correspondence work in that situation as well?

Comment: It sounds like (I might be wrong) your confusion is more to do with what an injective function is than anything?

Comment: Isn't the injective function just something that maps a value in one domain to another domain(could be the same)? Say f(x) = 4x, maps value in R, x, to value 4x in R as well.

Comment: You need to be more specific because, for example, a surjective function also "maps a value in one domain to another domain" but a surjection _does not_ imply an injection. An injective (or one to one) function is a function that maps every element from your set $A$ to _its own unique_ element in a set $B$.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention which book is "your book".

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that to the question

Comment: So surjective is the default meaning when you say something is a function. It just has to meet that requirement of mapping exactly one value in one domain to another domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying you can informally "list" a set isn't rigorous. This is given as an intuitive explanation only. This is made rigorous by saying $S$ is countably infinite if and only if there exists a bijective map

$$f:\mathbb{N}\to S.$$

From here you're free to call $f(1)$ the first element of the *list*, $f(2)$, the second, and so on. So by presenting such a function, you're giving a list

$$f(1), f(2), f(3),...$$

$\mathbb{N}$ is a natural choice as the domain, but it can be replaced with $\mathbb{Z}$ or any other countable set without affecting the true meaning.

Comment: Oh just like counting right? Say for positive even integers, i can count 2, 4, 6, 8. And that would be the function f(c) where a count number(positive) is mapped to the actual positive even integer. So 2 would be 1st positive integer, 4 my 2nd positive integer, and so on. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, and to prove it rigorously, you attempt to come up with a function which lists things as you think of the list. In this case $f(n)=2n$ would work to show the positive even integers are countable. You need to show it is bijective to finish it (which is easy).

Comment: And bijective is onto and one to one from what i remember?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as a one-to-one correspondence

Comment: David, can you take a look at my question on how to write a simple function to map a positive integer to a member of a Cartesian product set?

Comment: yeah i think it's better for me to define the function as                      f: Z+ -> S because my book includes 0 in the set of natural numbers.